# How to Call Methods in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have written some code in scala and created one method inside that now i want to call this method in another program but I'm not not getting any result after  calling this method.

First Program

```
object helper_class {
  def driver {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val sparksession = SparkSession.builder().appName("app").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
      val filepath: String = args(0)
      val d1 = spark.sql(s"load data inpath '${args(0)}'  into table databasename.tablename")
      //some more reusable code
    }
  }
}
```

second Program

```
import  Packagename.helper_class.driver
object child_program {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    driver //I want to call this method from  helper_class
  }
}
```

if I'm removing `def main(args: Array[String])`  from 1st code its giving error near  `args(0)` as   `args(0)` not found
       `args(0)` I am planning to pass as spark-submit
can someone please help me how should i Implement this.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to wrap the main method with driver method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `main` method is your entry point to run a program. It can't be wrapped within another method. Thus, you can't wrap it within another method.

I think what you are trying to do, is to load some Spark setup code and then use that "driver" to do something else... This is my best guess on how that could work

```
object ChildProgram {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val driver = Helper.driver(args)
    // do something with the driver
  }
}



object Helper {
    def driver(args: Array[String]) = {
      val sparksession = SparkSession.builder().appName("app").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
      val filepath: String = args(0)
      val d1 = spark.sql(s"load data inpath '${args(0)}'  into table databasename.tablename")
      //some more reusable code

      // I am assuming you are going to return the driver here
    }
}
```

That said, I would highly recommend reading a bit on Scala before attempting to go down that route, because you are likely to face even more obstacles. If I am to recommend a resource, you can try the awesome book "Scala for the Impatient" which should get you up and running very quickly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Muhammad Farag I have also declared some variables in Helper but whenever I m trying to access those variables its showing not found: value error.i.e. I have declared one variable val tablename=dbname.tablename.and this variable  I want to use in my 'ChildProgram' ."select * from  ${tablename}" Its showing "not found: value tablename"

Comment: I also tried using driver.tablename in this case its showing tablename  its not a member of Unit

Comment: I updated the code snippet and added a missing equal sign when declaring the driver function. The function will return the last value or you could use an explicit return. 

I think it would help you a lot if you spend some time on Scala itself.